# TrendsOverflow, quick trends from Stack Overflow

Tags: app, website, statistics

#### About:

TrendsOverflow is a very simple [website](http://trendsoverflow.educalleja.es/) that displays the number of questions per day for the most popular programming languages from Stack Overflow.

I created this application because I wanted to compare the popularity of different languages. I tried to use Google Trends but sometimes Google mixes data from programming languages and non-programming languages. I thought that data from Stack Overflow would be more accurate than the popularity provided by Google Trends, so I decided to retrieve this information by myself. As I did not find any published website offering this information, I decided to develop this very simple application by myself.

#### Screenshot:

[image: trends graph for css, django and javascript]

#### Download / Install:

To use, just visit the website, **[trendsoverflow.educalleja.es](http://trendsoverflow.educalleja.es)**, and enter your search terms.

#### Platform:

Only tested in Chrome. Let me know if you have any issues!

#### Contact:

Report any issue or comment in [the TrendsOverflow GitHub repository](https://github.com/educalleja/trendsoverflow).

#### Code:

Website wrote in Flask, Sqlite, SQLAlchemy.

Feel free to play with the code available at [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/educalleja/trendsoverflow).

Any contribution is welcome. Be aware that this is my first application developed in Flask, so if you have any comment or suggestion, feel free to contact me :)

Comment: Does not work with Firefox.  Gives `TypeError: fH.pc is not a function` error for starters.